# "The theory of organic architecture: that structure should appear " VS "the theory of organic architecture that structure should appear"

Tags: appositives

In the sentence below:

> The other theory underlying Wright's design is that of organic architecture: that structure should appear to be an extension of their surroundings. ( From an ACT test)

Question: I know the first that is referring to "theory," but what I am confused is that why colon is used here? Because I think the second "that" is leading an apposition clause explaining what the preceding " the theory of organic architecture" is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to punctuate that:
colon
comma
", that is"
", i.e."

[englishgrammar](https://www.englishgrammar101.com/module-14/additional-punctuation/lesson-3/colons)
Appositives After Independent Clauses

> Colons are used before appositives that follow an independent clause. A comma could also be used, but a colon is stronger. Use a colon instead of a comma when you want to emphasize or call special attention to the appositive.
> *I only like two flavors of ice cream: chocolate and vanilla.*
> *We visited a famous World Heritage Site: Stonehenge.*

The choice given is between a colon and no punctuation. Without punctuation, the last clause would be restrictive, that is, it would narrow the meaning of "organic architecture". Here, it doesn't narrow the meaning, but rather explains the meaning. That is, the clause is offered as an exact equivalent of "organic architecture". Thus, some kind of punctuation is needed.

See here for the application of the restrictive/non-restrictive distinction to appositives:
[englishgrammar101 restr/non-restr appositives](https://www.englishgrammar101.com/module-9/verbals-and-phrases/lesson-9/restrictive-and-nonrestrictive-appositives)

> An appositive noun or phrase is nonrestrictive (also called nonessential) if we know exactly who the writer is referring to when the appositive is removed. Nonrestrictive appositives simply add extra information, and they need commas around them.

Comment: May I ask how do I decide the writer is trying to emphasize the appositive?

Comment: If the writer used a colon, they were emphasizing.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear. The sentence is actually a in a question, and what is different from the right and wrong answer is whether there is a colon used.

Comment: I understand now. If there were no punctuation, even a comma, it would be a restrictive clause, narrowing the meaning of "organic architecture", but here it doesn't narrow the meaning; rather, it explains it. I will edit my answer to make it clear.

Comment: I am a little bit baffled. Since the function of appositives is to explain something, why would it narrow the meaning? I mean, it is not like relative clauses which have the distinction between restrictive relative clauses and non-restrictive relative clause.

Comment: That same distinction applies to appositives. i added a reference to the answer to elaborate that.

Comment: There is no appositive here. The colon avoids having to use a conjunction, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Sample sentence:

1. The other theory underlying Wright's design is that of organic architecture: that structure should appear to be an extension of their surroundings.

Sample sentence without the colon

2. The other theory underlying Wright's design is **that of** organic architecture and that structure should appear to be an extension of their surroundings.

The colon avoids saying "and that structure". It would be awkward here to have that of organic architecture followed by "and that". There is no appositive here as the second clause is a result, so to speak, of the first and not a restatement of it. An apposition is a restatement of something.

From Grammar Book.com
Rule 4. A colon instead of a semicolon may be used **between independent clauses** when the second sentence explains, illustrates, paraphrases, or expands on the first sentence.

Example: He got what he worked for: he really earned that promotion.

[Grammar Book][1]

[1]: [https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/colons.asp#:~:text=A%20colon%20means%20%22that%20is,unless%20it's%20a%20proper%20noun](https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/colons.asp#:%7E:text=A%20colon%20means%20%22that%20is,unless%20it%27s%20a%20proper%20noun)).